# Populate HTML input form element with data

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I wish to populate html input boxes with the data-id from certain elements.

```
<h2 class="postItem" data-id="23" href="#"></h2>
```

This an example of a H2 element I have in my site, what I wish to do is take this data-id and place it in a input box.

I am using JavaScript/MooTools to grab the data-ids see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4kzm/)

```
$$('.postItem').addEvent('click', function(e){
var el = e.target;
var id = el.getAttribute('data-id');
alert(id);
});
```

So my question is how do I then take this data-id and place it inside of a input box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean [this](http://jsfiddle.net/N4kzm/1/).

Just one simple line:

```
$('melp').value = id;
```

With `melp` of course being the `id` of the input element.

Comment: That's Mootools in a nutshell - simple (yes I'm a professional JQuery-hater ;)